# How to replace dot "." with comma "," in this simple C program?

Tags: c

This code works

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    float fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;
    lower = 0;      
    upper = 300;   
    step = 20;     

    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper)
    {
        celsius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32);
        printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

and return

```
  0  -17.8
 20   -6.7
 40    4.4
 60   15.6
 80   26.7
100   37.8
120   48.9
140   60.0
160   71.1
180   82.2
200   93.3
220  104.4
240  115.6
260  126.7
280  137.8
300  148.9
```

but I want something like that

```
  0  -17,8
 20   -6,7
 40    4,4
 60   15,6
 80   26,7
....
```

With "," instead of "."

How to escape ","?
I have tried "" and \ but I fail.
Forgive if is silly question but I am a newbie on C (i know this code + hello-world actually).

EDIT: I have found the solution and was easy using the locale library

This is the new code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

main()
{
float fahr, celsius;
int lower, upper, step;
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "it_IT.UTF-8");
lower=0;      
upper=300;     
step=20;

fahr=lower;
while (fahr<=upper)
{
celsius=(5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32);
printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
fahr=fahr+step;
}
}
```

and this is final result

```
  0  -17,8
 20   -6,7
 40    4,4
 60   15,6
 80   26,7
100   37,8
120   48,9
140   60,0
160   71,1
....
```

The only difference was to put `#include locale.h` and     `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "it_IT.UTF-8");`
If possible I ask for question reopen, I can add this an answer.

Comment: Minor note: this is called "replacing". "Escaping" a character means something else :) Please update the question and title if you want correct responses.

Comment: This is usually depending on the systems locale and regional settings, and nothing you should attempt to control through your program.